# Why do ListBox.ObjectCollection and ListView.ListViewItemCollection have AddRange but not InsertRange or RemoveRange?

Tags: .net, list, listview, listbox, ilist

So, both `ListBox.ObjectCollection` and `ListView.ListViewItemCollection` implement the `IList` class, which provides `Add` and `Remove` methods but no `AddRange`, `InsertRange`, or `RemoveRange`. However, `ListBox.ObjectCollection` and `ListView.ListViewItemCollection` also provide an `AddRange` method -- just no `InsertRange` or `RemoveRange`.

Look at the `ArrayList` class, on the other hand, which on top of implementing `IList` also provides `AddRange`, `InsertRange`, and `RemoveRange`. The same difference exists between the generic forms of this class and interface, `List<T>` (which has `AddRange`, `InsertRange`, and `RemoveRange`) and `IList<T>` (which only provides `Add` and `Remove`).

I can understand the `IList` and `IList<T>` interfaces not providing `AddRange`, etc. -- it's just an interface; anything beyond the minimum requirements of `Add`, `Remove`, `RemoveAt`, etc. is optional. But, given the usefulness of the `*Range` methods for the `ArrayList` and `List<T>` classes, and considering how handy they'd be for `ListBox` and `ListView` controls, I wonder why they don't exist for these controls.

Does anyone know? **Is there something about the internal implementation of `InsertRange` and `RemoveRange` that makes these methods somehow less efficient, more complicated, or otherwise less appropriate for `ListBox.ObjectCollection` and `ListView.ListViewItemCollection` than `AddRange`?**

To be clear: I'm not looking for speculation of the "Looks like someone at Microsoft got lazy" variety; rather, I'm wondering if anyone actually *knows* of a legitimate difference between `AddRange` and `InsertRange`/`RemoveRange` that might explain the absence of these latter methods from `ListBox.ObjectCollection` and `ListView.ListViewItemCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general it's a pretty uncommon scenario to use InsertRange and (even more so) RemoveRange. Should RemoveRange, for example, remove the given range only if there is a *continious* range of elements similar to the given range, or should it remove the given elements one by one?
2. These methods are usually easy to implement if you need them. With the help of the extension methods you can have them to look almost like the native methods.
3. There are no signs in the code, showing that it would be complicated to implement those methods (just as thousands of other "useful" methods). Actually, the `ListView` implementation of `InsertItems` even takes an *array* of items already under the hood. Just the standard `ListViewItemCollection.Insert()` always provides array with 1 element. Take a look with the Reflector to the `ListViewNativeItemCollection.Insert()`:

   ```
    public ListViewItem Insert(int index, ListViewItem item)
    {
        //Various checks excluded ....
        this.owner.InsertItems(index, new ListViewItem[] { item }, true);
        //More code excluded .....
        return item;
    }
   ```

I guess it just wasn't that important to implement that feature... so they didn't.

As Eric Lippert [likes to say](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx): "because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature".

Comment: I suppose this answer makes a lot of sense. However, it seems from your first point that you are talking about RemoveRange as if it were a function that takes an IEnumerable or otherwise some kind of *range* as a parameter; but the List.RemoveRange method simply takes two integers: index (where to start removing) and count (how many elements to remove). Using a definition similar to this one, the complication you mention in your first point seems irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, I see... Still I'd say it's rarely needed. Maybe it's important for your scenario, but I've never used those methods in my experience.

Comment: The reason why `RemoveRange` would be so useful is because removing a range of item is likely to be an order of magnitude faster than removing them one by one (at least based on the performance charactaristics of `AddRange`).